# How to select polygons that don't intersect with line but with its buffer?

Tags: postgis

I have lines and polygons in a PostGIS database. The lines may intersect with these polygons. I want to select all polygons that **do not** intersect with a line but **do** intersect with its buffered area.

Currently I have the following query:

```
    SELECT
        f.*
    FROM 
        polygons f 
        INNER JOIN lines l ON ST_Intersects(f.geom, ST_Buffer(l.geom, 50))
    WHERE 
        f.id NOT IN (
            SELECT 
                f.id
            FROM 
                polygons f 
                INNER JOIN lines l ON ST_Intersects(f.geom, l.geom)   
        )
```

This query takes very long and I was wondering if there is a more performative way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the buffer, the spatial index is not used. Because of the inner join, you are building a buffer for every line and for every polygon.

I would use `st_dwithin` instead of a buffer, which makes use of available spatial indexes.

Also, I would use the same layer reference for the exclusion sub query

```
SELECT
   f.*
FROM 
   polygons f 
  INNER JOIN lines l ON ST_DWithin(f.geom,l.geom, 50)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM lines l2 
      WHERE ST_Intersects(f.geom, l2.geom)   
      )
```

The above query ensure that there is no intersecting line at all, but will select the polygons multiple times if there are multiple lines within the proper distance.

To select a polygons once only, regardless of the number of nearby lines, the query would be

```
SELECT
   f.*
FROM 
   polygons f 
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM lines l 
      WHERE ST_DWithin(f.geom,l.geom, 50)  
      )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM lines l2 
      WHERE ST_Intersects(f.geom, l2.geom)   
      )
```

If you want to work with single lines only (that is, apply the polygon selection per line, so if a line is at valid distance and a 2nd one is intersecting the polygon the polygon would be selected), the query can be simplified to

```
SELECT
   f.*
FROM 
   polygons f 
  INNER JOIN lines l 
     ON ST_DWithin(f.geom,l.geom, 50) 
     AND ST_Intersects(f.geom, l.geom) = FALSE
```

or, to remove duplicates, to

```
SELECT
   f.*
FROM 
   polygons f 
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM lines l 
      WHERE ST_DWithin(f.geom,l.geom, 50)
         AND ST_Intersects(f.geom, l.geom) = FALSE    
      )
```